# Class variable not updating

Tags: python, class, python-3.6

I have the following basic class involving a circle.  My question is, when I directly update the diameter with c.diameter(10), how come the radius is updated to 5?  As the output shows, it is still at 4:

```
from math import pi


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.radius = radius
        self.diameter = self.radius * 2

    def diameter(self, diameter):
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.radius = self.diameter / 2
        return self.radius, self.diameter

    def area(self):
        return self.radius ** 2 * pi


c = Circle(3)
print("c.radius:", c.radius)
print("c.area():", c.area())
c.radius = 4  # change radius
print("c.radius:", c.radius)
print("c.area():", c.area())
c.diameter = 10  # change diameter
print("c.diameter:", c.diameter)
print("c.radius:", c.radius)
```

Output:

```
c.radius: 3
c.area(): 28.274333882308138
c.radius: 4
c.area(): 50.26548245743669
c.diameter: 10
c.radius: 4   <--- Radius should be 5, since the Radius is Diameter / 2
```

Comment: Why do you have both a method named `diameter` and an attribute named `diameter`? The latter will mask the method, you can't have both.

Comment: Flagged as a simple typographical error.

Comment: You should do `c.diameter(10)` instead of `c.diameter = 10` (which just updates the `diameter` attribute and nothing else)

Comment: @Drise: it is not, they have **two** problems.

Comment: @LaurentH.:  `c.diameter(10)` instead of `c.diameter = 10` won't work because the class's diameter method is hidden by the object's attribute of the same name.  He would have to do `Circle.diameter(c, 10)` to make the call work (which doesn't solve the problem so much as illustrate it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two things named `diameter`:

- An attribute on the instance, set with `self.diameter` in `__init__` and with `c.diameter = 10` later on.
- A method on the class named `diameter`. This method is never accessed. You can't access it on the instance, because there the `diameter` attribute *masks* the method.

On Python classes, methods are still just attributes. `c.area` returns the method object, and only `c.area()` actually calls the method.

So, just referencing `c.diameter` will not actually give you the method, it gives you the attribute on the instance, which is just an integer object.

You have two options:

- Rename the method, to `set_diameter()` for example.
- Make the `diameter` attribute a [*property* object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Properties are used *as you would an attribute*, but getting or setting the attribute on an instance triggers methods to be called.

The latter option is the 'pythonic' option, the method experienced Python developers would use:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self.radius * 2

    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, value):
        self.radius = value / 2

    def area(self):
        return self.radius ** 2 * pi
```

The `@property` / `@diameter.setter` pair of decorators define the getter and setter for the property; the first `def diameter` is called whenever you want to *read* (*get*) the value of the attribute, and the second is used when *writing* called when you try to assign a new value (the *setter*):

```
>>> c = Circle(3)
>>> c.diameter
6
>>> c.diameter = 4
>>> c.radius
2.0
>>> c.diameter
4.0
```

Note that we never set an attribute named `diameter` in the setter! The value is instead always calculated when you access `c.diameter` for reading.

You'll also notice that when you assign an integer to the `diameter` attribute, that the radius becomes a `float` value; that's because the `/` operator always produces a float value, even for integer inputs. Use `//` (floor division), if you always must have an integer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use properties with according setters to make sure you update your internal data:

Something like this:

```
from math import pi


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self._radius = radius
        self._diameter = radius * 2

    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self._diameter

    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, diameter):
        self._diameter = diameter
        self._radius = diameter / 2

    @property  
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        self._radius = radius
        self._diameter = radius * 2

    def area(self):
        return self.radius ** 2 * pi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Circle(3)
    print("c.radius:", c.radius)
    print("c.area():", c.area())
    c.radius = 4  # change radius
    print("c.radius:", c.radius)
    print("c.area():", c.area())
    c.diameter = 10  # change diameter
    print("c.diameter:", c.diameter)
    print("c.radius:", c.radius)
```